# Unable to download device for Xamarin Android Player , Getting Operation Time out Error

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-android-player

I am not able to download any device from device list of XAP.

Do not have any logs at ProgramData or \Program Files\Xamarin Android Player. I am behind a corporate proxy. Do I need to configure proxy some where ?

I also tried from home, and it times out after downloading around 40 MB!!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My (rather obvious) guess is that the proxy is interfering somehow.  You can access the logs as so:

1. Right click the bottom bar of the Device Manager (the window you have screen shot)
2. Click on 'Generate Bug Report'
3. Check your Desktop for the resulting zip file containing the logs.

Xamarin Android Player is Preview software and any issues are best reported in a [bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Xamarin%20Android%20Player).

It may also be wise to check out the [Visual Studio Android Emulator](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx) or the official Google AVD for which the x86 images with HAXM support offer far better performance than their earlier counterparts.  You can download the images through the Android SDK Manager or set up the devices via Android Studio if you have it installed.